# Program freezes when saving any file

Tags: tag

Running latest Ubuntu. When saving  text file program freezes and I can’t save or close unless I kill it. Still learning Linux can you guys help me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue a bit? Please update your question to include the application you’re editing files with, perhaps their size, and maybe even the brand and model of your computer. This might make it possible for someone to offer something of value to solve your problem …

Comment: Please also define the *latest* Ubuntu...  Please be precise, as the *latest* stable release is Ubuntu 21.04 for a *deb* based system, or Ubuntu Core 20 for a *snap* only based device release... Which is *latest* to you? or do you mean an earlier release (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which is 3 releases ago even ignoring specialist releases)